# phantomjs not capturing screenshot from https website

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to capture simple screenshot using phantomjs for https://www.google.com . Screenshot is coming as blank . I am using eclipse in windows and jars phantomjsdriver1.1 , selenium jars all 2.39 version .

When I mention site as http://google , it redirects to https and captures screenshot . But I need it to exclusively capture it for https only . Below is my code . Thanks in advance .

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import net.anthavio.phanbedder.Phanbedder;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class Schedule {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File phantomjs = Phanbedder.unpack();

        DesiredCapabilities dcaps = new DesiredCapabilities();

        dcaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, phantomjs.getAbsolutePath());
        dcaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
        String [] phantomJsArgs = {"---ignore-ssl-errors=yes"};
        dcaps.setCapability(
                PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_CLI_ARGS, 
                phantomJsArgs);

        PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcaps);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\fci\\sample.jpeg"),true); 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception");
        }

        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? I mean the executable version and not the driver version.

Comment: I am using phanbedder-1.9.7-1.0.0.jar . Inside this jar there is exe for windows - phantomjs.exe

Comment: this is the version of exe phantomjs

\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs-1.9.7\phantomjs.exe

Comment: Your `phantomJsArgs` value is wrong. First,  there are only two leading dashes not three for commandline options. Second, such an old PhantomJS version needs another commandline option: `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1`. Tell me how it went.

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS is a headless browser meaning; you don't get to see what is happening; everything that's done is done in background.